# Indian numbering system formatting

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, fixed-point

The following code converts a number into [Indian numbering system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system) format.

I know locale can also help in getting similar format but I wanted something that can work on any system because not all locales are present in all OSs.

The code was written for Python 3.5 hence no variable annotations.

```
from decimal import Decimal
from itertools import islice, zip_longest
from typing import Any, Iterable, Iterator, Sequence, Tuple, TypeVar, Union  # noqa: ignore=F401


_T = TypeVar('_T')


def grouper(iterable: Iterable[_T], n: int, fillvalue: Any = None) -> Iterator[Tuple[_T, ...]]:
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)


def indian_numbering_format(
    amount: Union[Decimal, int, str], places: int = 2,
    curr: str = '', pos: str = '', neg: str = '-'
) -> str:
    """
    Formats a number and returns it in Indian numbering format
    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_numbering_system

    places:  optional number of places after the decimal point
    curr:    optional currency symbol before the sign
    pos:     optional sign for positive numbers: '+' or blank
    neg:     optional sign for negative numbers: '-' or blank

    Note that if the fractional part only contains 0 it will be
    dropped.
    """
    q = Decimal(10) ** -places  # type: Decimal
    amount = Decimal(amount).quantize(q)
    sign, digits, exponent = amount.as_tuple()
    integer_part, fractional_part = (), ()  # type: Sequence[int], Sequence[int]
    exponent = exponent or len(digits)
    integer_part = digits[:exponent]
    # If fractional part only contains 0s then ignore it.
    if set(digits[exponent:]) != {0}:
        fractional_part = digits[exponent:]
    integer_part_digits = reversed(''.join(map(str, integer_part)))
    thousand = ''.join(islice(integer_part_digits, 3))[::-1]
    hundreds = ','.join(map(''.join, grouper(integer_part_digits, 2, fillvalue='')))[::-1]
    sep = ',' if hundreds else ''
    fractional_part_digits = '.' + ''.join([str(d) for d in fractional_part]) if fractional_part else ''
    return '{sign}{curr}{hundreds}{sep}{thousand}{fractional_part}'.format(
        sign=neg if sign else pos,
        curr=curr,
        thousand=thousand,
        sep=sep,
        hundreds=hundreds,
        fractional_part=fractional_part_digits
    )
```

I was wondering if the code can be refactored in any way to make it much more simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think I'd get so fancy with the grouper; the data is small, a constant table will do:

```
comma_after_digit = set(3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17)

result = '.' + ''.join(map(str, fractional_part))
for i, d in enumerate(integer_part_digits):
    if i in comma_after_digit:
        result = ',' + result
    result = d + result
result = {0:pos, 1:neg}[sign] + result
return result
```

Also:

2. Try and be a bit more consistent: you use `reversed()` to reverse a string on one line, and then the next you use `[::-1]`.  You also use `map(str, digits)` in one place and `[str(x) for x in digits]` another! They do the same thing, but it's nice to the reader to pick one idiom and stick with it.
3. `thousand = ''.join(islice(integer_part_digits, 3))[::-1]` can be simplified into `thousand = integer_part_digits[-4::-1]`
4. Using `.format()` is overkill for concatenating strings.  `+` works just fine.  If you want to use it, you should 1) factor out constant strings (like the decimal point) and 2) use the args as your temporary variables, like:

   ```
   return '{sign}{curr}{hundreds}{sep}{thousand}.{fractional_part}'.format(
       sign=neg if sign else pos,
       curr=curr,
       thousand=integer_part_digits[-4::-1],
       sep=',' if exponent > 3 else '',
       hundreds=','.join(map(''.join, grouper(integer_part_digits, 2, fillvalue='')))[::-1],
       fractional_part=''.join(map(str,fractional_part)) if fractional_part else ''
   )
   ```
5. According to the wikipedia page you cite, there's no comma after the 1 in 10**19, so your code is wrong :) ... which leads inevitably to:
6. Needs tests!

Comment: Good answer. For 2, I'd suggest for OP to stick to list comprehension. For 4, refer to [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/376461/string-concatenation-vs-string-substitution-in-python) post, since performance varies when concatenating vs substituting strings.

Comment: 5. I think 10**19 defined on Wiki page is incorrect because [LC_MONETARY for en_IN](https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/en_IN/) says the grouping structure is `3;2`. I already have decent number of tests :-).  2. Agreed with the inconsistency part, I had to introduce the map inconsistency due to some issue with Mypy, but I guess I should add a comment about it. 4. The idea behind using format string there is that we will replace it with a f-string when we move to Python 3.6, it would be much more compact after that.